# Check whether drive is main drive

Tags: c#, windows, driveinfo

I've got a DriveInfo object. 
I want to find out whether the drive is the Windows Drive(on my PC it's C:) because you can't right to the root directory of the Windows Drive.

Comment: It depends what you mean by the "main drive".  It sounds like you actually want to check the permissions.

Comment: Agree with SLaks. What is the ultimate goal of your program?

Comment: To write to the root directory of the drive and if it's the main drive then write it to AppData

Comment: I think there's a lot more context missing, but that sounds not unreasonable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `string path = Path.GetPathRoot(Environment.SystemDirectory);` and than check agains the drive name, like `C:\` or `D:\`, ...

Comment: I have that in one of my programs and I was wondering if there was a better way of doing it but thanks.